# Use mod-rewrite or redirect to redirect website relaunch?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I will soon relaunch my whole website on the same domain, and so i would like to redirect all old url's to the new homepage. I've been looking around and have found lots of ways to do that, but no one works for me. I guess i need help from someone who really understands.

The current url's are like this:

```
http://www.ffsolar.com/produtos/index.php?lingua=por
http://www.ffsolar.com/contacto/index.php?lingua=eng
http://www.ffsolar.com/inicio/index.php?lingua=ger
```

Which i want to redirect to the new

```
http://www.ffsolar.com
```

The old folders and files will no longer exist after the relaunch, so i think that the redirect 301 method won't work.

So, my question is how do i do that? Do i have to use a mod-rewrite, or a simple redirect for all the old url's?

Comment: Nobody to answer this question? :S

Comment: If the pages aren't going to exist, they should return 404 status codes, not a redirect to the home page with status 200.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `ErrorDocument 404 /`

Or you create a RewriteRule for each url that no longer exists:

**E.g.:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/produtos(.*)$ / [R]
RewriteRule ^/contacto(.*)$ / [R]
RewriteRule ^/inicio(.*)$ / [R]
```

You could also use `RewriteRule ^produtos(.*)$ http://www.ffsolar.com/ [R]`

So every url with e.g. **/produtos** or **/contacto** or **/inicio** will be redirected to the document root of this domain.

Also http://www.ffsolar.com/**produtos/index.php?lingua=por** or even http://www.ffsolar.com**/produtos/just/example/random.php**

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! Thank you so much!